# Bash and Git Flow bug in common file

Tags: git, bash, git-flow

I have already installed the `Git Flow` that seems to be an excellent tool, but when I run the command `git flow feature start Test` I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-flow: 301: export: Internal/WPLion/gitflow/.git: bad variable name
```

So I tried to find out what's wrong, and I found that inside the file `/user/lib/git-core/gitflow-common` the script fails to execute the following code:

```
export DOT_GIT_DIR=$(cd "$DOT_GIT_DIR" && pwd)
```

that is on line `301`.

To *debug* the script I use the commands `echo` and `exit 1` to break the execution, so the code before the 301 is the following:

```
DOT_GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
```

so when I use the above command   I get the following result on my bash:

```
.
```

and when I try to `echo` anything after the line 301 of course the script breaks.

Also when I try to execute the code `git rev-parse --git-dir` that it's result is getting saved in the variable `DOT_GIT_DIR` the result is the following:

```
/media/merianos/Large Internal/WPLion/gitflow/.git
```

that is actually the path to git repository inside my project folder.

So, what's wrong with that code? The path spaces maybe making the issue?

Comment: your initial error looks like its caused by the space in your path

Comment: Is there a way to fix it ? I am totally new on Linux, and this is actually the second bash script I use :)

Comment: your fix looks fine - alternatively you would probably have to use a spaceless path

Comment: As I described above, I am totally new on Linux, and got for me too hard setup Apache running with an external HD (Large Internal), so I don't touch it anymore :) xaxaxa

Answer (score 0):

ok, I fixed the issue by my self.

I know that it's not permanent, but I will also try to contribute on the main repository, and fix the bug.

The modification I did, was on file `/user/lib/git-core/gitflow-common` (*Ubuntu system*) on lines **301** and **302** and the code was like that:

```
export DOT_GIT_DIR=$(cd "$DOT_GIT_DIR" && pwd)
export HOOKS_DIR=$(git config --get gitflow.path.hooks || echo "$DOT_GIT_DIR"/hooks) # the second option is used to support previous versions of git-flow
```

and It became like that:

```
export DOT_GIT_DIR="$(cd $DOT_GIT_DIR && pwd)"
export HOOKS_DIR="$(git config --get gitflow.path.hooks || echo "$DOT_GIT_DIR"/hooks)" # the second option is used to support previous versions of git-flow
```

Comment: What shell are you using? And what version of that shell? What does `export foo=$(echo foo bar); declare -p foo` output in your shell?

Comment: I use the GNOME Terminal in 3.14.2, and the result is : `declare -x foo="foo bar"`

Comment: GNOME Terminal is the terminal not the shell but that output would indicate that your fix of adding quotes there shouldn't have changed anything in the scripts about the safety of whitespace in the paths. So I don't see how that should have fixed the problem.

Comment: To be honest I don't even know what is the difference between the bash and the shell. Also, what I know, is that the modification I made, allowing the script now to run, rather than returning any error message. As already have describe, this is the second shell script I touch in my life, so don't expect from me any answer :)

Comment: Can you add `set -x` just above those lines (and `set +x`) just below them and then run the script (without the quotes you added and then with) and show the output?